# How to install Fennec on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, firefox, fennec

I just downloaded it from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile

> Developer Tools
>
> You can install the mobile version of Firefox to your desktop computer in order to test, provide feedback, and build add-ons.

But I don't know how to install it. I wanna test my web page on Firefox Mobile.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an installer. Just click the download button under developer tools, extract the downloaded zip somewhere, and run fennec.exe from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get latest windows desktop release
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/releases/10.0/win32/